# Decomposition of semi-simple Lie algebra into simple lie algebra (or ideal?)

Tags: lie-algebras, ideals, semisimple-lie-algebras

A semi-simple Lie algebra $L$ can by definition be decomposed into simple Lie algebras :

$L=L_1\oplus \ldots \oplus L_n $. Are these $L_i$ necessarily ideals of $L$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the direct summands are ideals by definition, since a Lie algebra direct sum $L=L_1\oplus L_2$ is defined with the Lie bracket $[L_1,L_2]=0$. Hence we have
$$[L_1,L]=[L_1,L_1\oplus L_2]=[L_1,L_1]\oplus[L_1,L_2]=L_1,$$ hence $L_1$ is an ideal. The same is true for $L_2$.

Comment: o_O. I didn't notice this.

Comment: Could $[L_1,L_1]$ be ${0}$ instead of $L_1$?

Comment: No, $L_1$ is simple, hence perfect, i.e., $[L_1,L_1]=L_1$.

Comment: Oh, right, by definition $L_1$ is not Abelian, I always forget.
So $L_1$ and $L_2$ inside $L$ are in direct sum as vector spaces means $L_1\cap L_2=0$ and $L_1+L_2=L$ and to be direct sum of Lie algebra means we also have $[L_1,L_2]=0$ right?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: But is it true in general? Is a simple subalgebra always an ideal?

Comment: @roi_saumon Of course not, semisimple algebra with a higher rank has a sl(2,F) per root as a subalgebra which is simple but not ideal when the inner product (with respect to the Killing form) of this root with some other is nonzero.